# Visual Studio 2017 Design XAML bug, não reconhece resources

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2017

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
internal static System.Drawing.Bitmap radio_hover_btn {
    get {
        object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("radio_hover_btn", 
resourceCulture);
        return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
    }
}
```

Estou com problemas nesse código acima, simplesmente ele não acha o meu png `radio_hover_btn` e alega erro durante a execução:

> System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException ocorrido
>     HResult=0x80131532
>     Message=Nenhum recurso adequado para a cultura especificada (ou a cultura neutra) foi encontrado no assembly dado. Verifique se "truckersmplauncher.Properties.Resources.resources" foi incorporado ou vinculado ao assembly "TruckersMPLauncher" corretamente no tempo de compilação ou se todos os assemblies satélites necessários podem ser carregados e estão totalmente assinados.

Os "botões" que na verdade são imagens ficam com cor transparente, mas ainda executam a função de clique.

Comment: Tente ir na imagem > Properties > Build Action e selecione Embedded Resource.

Comment: Ainda continua dando Bug, ele dá exceção sem tratamento